# what is mono project

Tags: c#, mono

what is mono project , can this help me to run my winform software on macosx . is it secure ?
can I install mono instead of .netframework ?

Comment: No one will explain it better than the Mono team itself. http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page .

Comment: Are you just to lazzy to google for mono? Cheese

Comment: Of course no one can explain better then, but a lot of people can share their expreiences about Mono.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Mono Rocks!**

What can I say, **I simply LOVE IT**... It brings the .NET framework to all *nix machines, including Mac OSX.

and all this, includes the fantastic MonoTouch (though it requires a license from Novel) to develop **Native iPhone apps** in... .NET language!

there are 3 things you need to know to start developing your "winforms" under Mac.

- Install **Mono Framework** (kinda like you need to install **.NET 3.5**)
- Install **MonoDevelop** (it's the Mono IDE, kinda like **Visual Studio**)

***added 3rd thingy that you should be aware of***

- You can easily convert winforms to osx forms, the code behind it's a simple copy paste of all your methods, but the GUI is a little tricky and you should know how the **[Interface Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder)** works so you can understand the linkage between **GUI** and **Code**.

if you want to take a deeper look without starting and installing nothing, take a look at the [Session EX02](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX02) that Miguel presented at MIX 2010, intitled **[The Mono Project](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX02)**

Comment: 3 things that we need to know - but you forgot to mention one of them? :-)

Comment: eheh, you right ... I got lost with Miguel video and forgot to add the 3rd :D ... added ;)

Answer (score 7):

**Mono is an open source implementation of .NET framework**. *Yes it can run winform apps on both mac and linux. But to get the native look and feel of Mac you should probably use  cocoa# bindings on Mac* rather than the winforms gui library. With Monotouch it can also let your C# application run on iPhone. With Monodroid it can run your C# app on Android ... etc etc

See the following for more info:
1)  for general information http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page
2)  for iPhone development with mono http://monotouch.net/
3)  for Mac download http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

**Monodevelop is the Visual Studio equivalent for Mono development**. Get it from http://monodevelop.com/

Answer (score 2):

Mono project is targeting to run .NET Framework on Linux and MacOS.

But there are a lot of problem and the project proceeds slowly.

I don't know the current state but I know you can create WinForms on Linux and with MonoLight you can create Silverlight applications.

You can get more information from [Mono-Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

Answer (score 1):

The [home page](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) of the Mono project has most of the information you need. I'll quote some relevant bits:

> An open source, cross-platform, implementation of C# and the CLR that is binary compatible with Microsoft.NET
>
> Mono is a software platform designed to allow developers to easily create cross platform applications. Sponsored by Novell, Mono is an open source implementation of Microsoft's .NET Framework based on the ECMA standards for C# and the Common Language Runtime. A growing family of solutions and an active and enthusiastic contributing community is helping position Mono to become the leading choice for development of Linux applications

Answer (score 1):

Mono is

> An open source, cross-platform,
>   implementation of C# and the CLR that
>   is binary compatible with
>   Microsoft.NET

Therefore, you use mono instead of .net framework on not-windows native machine like Ubuntu, OSX.

You can use MonoDevelop to build your application with C# code. refer: http://monodevelop.com/